# Select only the entries common to all rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have this table and would like to query only the entries common to all rows (Log Id).

```
 Log Id   Person Id  Main(Y/N)  Sex    Rel       
   01           21   Y           M     ATH       
   02           21   Y           M     ATH       
   03           21   Y           F     ATH       
   04           21   Y           M     ATH       
   05           21   Y           F     ATH
```

The expected result would be like this:

```
PersonId  Y/N   Sex   Rel     
     21    Y     -    ATH
```

You see I wanted to only show what is common to all rows, otherwise null. This is only a part of a really complex query. Below is the big deal of a problem.

```
 Log Id   Person Id  Main(Y/N)  Sex    Rel       
   01           21   Y           M     ATH       
   02           21   Y           M     ATH       
   03           21   Y           F     ATH       
   04           21   Y           M     ATH       
   05           21   Y           F     ATH       
   01           22   N           M     ATH       
   02           22   N           M     ATH       
   03           22   N           M     ATH       
   04           22   N           M     ATH       
   05           22   N           M     ATH
```

The expected result would be like this:

```
PerId  Y/N  S   Rel    
  21    Y   -   ATH    
  22    N   M   ATH
```

Comment: you have both `Y` and `N` for `22`. Then why result should contain `N` for `22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work:

```
select personId,
       (case when count(distinct main)>1 then '' else main end) as Main,
       (case when count(distinct sex) >1 then '' else sex  end) as Sex,
       (case when count(distinct religion)>1 then '' else religion end) as Religion
from yourTableName
group by personId;
```

**Results:**

```
    personId | Main | Sex | Religion
     21      |  Y   |     |  ATH
     22      |  N   |  M  |  ATH
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://rextester.com/NDR28234)

**ORACLE SOLUTION:** (As suggested by @MarmiteBomber)

```
select personId,
       (case when count(distinct main)=1 then max(main) else ' ' end) as Main,
       (case when count(distinct sex)=1 then max(sex) else ' ' end) as Sex,
       (case when count(distinct religion)=1 then max(religion) else ' ' end) as Religion
from t
group by personId;
```

[DEMO in Oracle](http://rextester.com/NJAP9739)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm getting a not a GROUP BY expression for columns other than personId

Comment: Are you sure that you're using MySQL?

Comment: @TribensonAzupardo for `Oracle`you must also enclose the column with aggregation function such es `MAX` or `MIN`. E.g. `case when count(distinct main)>1 then NULL else max(main) end`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thank you. Can you please explain the reason behind that?

Comment: Simple in a query with `GROUP BY ` all referenced attributes taht are NOT in group by must be enclosed with an aggregate function. I'm wondering how it can work in MySQL.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thank you for the info. In Mysql, it's not mandatory to have all non-aggregate columns from select in group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select personId,
       (case when min(main) = max(main) then max(main) end) as Main,
       (case when min(sex) = max(sex) then max(sex) end) as Sex,
       (case when min(religion) = max(religion) then max(religion) end) as Religion
from yourTableName
group by personId;
```

Note:  This uses `NULL` for an unknown value.  I think this is much more in line with SQL.  You can use `else '-'` if you really want a hyphen.

Why use `min()` and `max()` instead of `count(distinct)`?  The reason is simple:  performance.  `count(distinct)` is more expensive than other aggregation operations (because the intermediate result has to store a list of all possible values).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I've one question though: suppose there are many personIds with 10-15 religion. Does min() and max() is cheaper than count() in this scenario too?

Comment: @Harshil . . . `min()` and `max()` are faster than *`count(distinct)`*.  The issue is the `distinct`.  Yes, that is true especially when there are more rows.